# C# - Dynamic SQL Script Generation

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, dynamic, nested-loops

I have an requirement to generate a dynamic SQL script using C#. Main reason for this requirement is ensure accurate unique counts at many possible levels for reporting.

### Background

**Table 1** - Holds list of SQL scripts template(s) as per example below:

```
ID  TemplateSQL
1   SELECT [Period],[OperatingSystem],[Application],[Version],COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS NUMBEROFCUSTOMERS
    FROM F_CUSTOMERACTIVITY
    WHERE SUMMARYDATE BETWEEN [Start Date] AND [End Date]
    [PeriodCriterion]
    [OperatingSystemCriterion]
    [ApplicationCriterion]
    [VersionCriterion]
    GROUP BY [Period],[OperatingSystem],[Application],[Version];
```

**Table 2** - Holds list of SQL snippet references that can be used when generating the dyanamic SQL script as per example below:

```
ID  TemplateID  TypeID  Parameter         ParameterSQL                 Criterion                  CriterionSQL
1   1           1       [Period]          SUMMARYDATE                  [PeriodCriterion]          NULL
2   1           1       [Period]          DATENAME(MONTH,SUMMARYDATE)  [PeriodCriterion]          NULL
3   1           1       [Period]          DATEPART(YEAR,SUMMARYDATE)   [PeriodCriterion]          NULL
4   1           2       [OperatingSystem] OPERATSYS                    [OperatingSystemCriterion] AND OPERATSYS = 'Windows'
5   1           2       [OperatingSystem] 'All Windows'                [OperatingSystemCriterion] AND OPERATSYS = 'Windows'
Etc....
```

**Process** - What is required is to first retrieve the template and subsequently generate a dynamic SQL script using every possible combination based on the available eligible snippets within table 2 which is related to that particular template. Example below:

```
ssql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, TEMPLATESQL, ";
ssql = ssql + "FROM TABLE1 ";
ssql = ssql + "WHERE ID = 1 ";

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

TdDataAdapter adapter1 = new TdDataAdapter(ssql, cn);

adapter1.Fill(dt1);

foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
{

    ssql = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, TEMPLATEID, PARAMETER, PARAMETERSQL, CRITERION, CRITERIONSQL ";
    ssql = ssql + "FROM TABLE2 ";
    ssql = ssql + "WHERE TEMPLATEID = 1 AND OS.TYPEID = 1 ";

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    TdDataAdapter adapter2 = new TdDataAdapter(ssql, cn);

    adapter2.Fill(dt2);

    foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
    {
        
        tsql = row[1].ToString();

        tsql = tsql.Replace(row2[2].ToString(), row2[3].ToString());
        tsql = tsql.Replace(row2[4].ToString(), row2[5].ToString());
    
    }
    
...
```

**Problem** - My current solution is to use nested loops to retrieve and cycle through each snippet to produce a dynamic SQL script but I believe this is a poor approach. Producing this requirement within anything other than C# is out of the question due to restrictions.

### Question

What would be the best approach for this requirement using C#?

Any suggestions and ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ben Jammin

Comment: Question does the generated permutations stay within the program or are they passed off to be used say in the SQL manager?  If the program is to just show the results from all permutations then I'd personally pick Entity Framework to get the template and use it along with T4 or Razor templates to auto-generate the permuted queries.  If you are able to use EF all the way through you can use IQueryable to add permutations as you go prior to executing the query.  This would mean you'd create a series of IQueryable methods.

Comment: Correct, stays within the program. Interesting thought with EF, I have used  it before but not for this purpose. I am not aware of the T4 and Razor engines but I will investigate. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Ok so now that we know the queries "stay" and are executed in the program.  You can use EF with writing IQueryable parts. Anytime you write a LINQ query without executing it, you can add other IQueryable parts prior to execution.  All you need to do is code up a controller that decides which parts to put together to get all permutations.  All this means is that you'll create lots of small filters that are added together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
public static class qry
{
    public static IQueryable Period(DateTime date) { return db.F_CustomerActivity.Where(p => p.Period == date); }
    public static IQueryable OperatingSystem(string system) { return db.F_CustomerActivity.Where(p => p.OperatingSystem == system); }
    public static IQueryable Application(string application) { return db.F_CustomerActivity.Where(p => p.Application == application); }
    public static IQueryable Version(string version) { return db.F_CustomerActivity.Where(p => p.Version == version); }
    public static IQueryable CustomerID(int id) { return db.F_CustomerActivity.Where(p => p.CustomerID == id); }
    public static IQueryable add(this IQueryable qry, Func<IQueryable> func)
    {
        var callback = func();
        return callback;
    }
```

And a controller class to put the permutations together...

```
public class controller
{
    public controller()
    {
       var stuff =  GetData();

    }

    private static async Task<List<object>> GetData()
    {
        IQueryable CurrentPermutation = null;
        var IQuerableList = new List<object>();
        foreach (var test in db.Permutations)
        {
            CurrentPermutation = qry.Application(test.Application)
            .add(() => qry.OperatingSystem(test.OperatingSystem))
            .add(() => qry.CustomerID(test.CustomerID))
            .add(() => qry.Version(test.Version));             
            var results = await CurrentPermutation.ToListAsync();
            IQuerableList.AddRange(results);
        }
        return IQuerableList;
    }

}
```

Each of the items in the list, are not executed until you kick them off using a method like ToList();

Comment: Thanks John... I am looking into your EF approach and trying to get a console example working. Any help in getting achieving this would be much appreciated. EF is quite new to me. Thanks, Ben

Comment: Yes here's a tip, search for Entity Framework Database First video.  Skip the ASP.NET lessons for now (unless you're using this in web site).  It's easy once you cut through to what you need, simply add EF as a reference, then use the EF Wizard, to point to table you want, then you have everything you need to access the database via Models or what they call Entities. Look on Youtube for Entity Framework Wizard too.

Comment: Thanks, setting up EF wasn't a problem, when trying to use your example, thats when I am coming into difficulties.